# How to create a table with the first column's width set to fit content and the rest equal spaced over the full container width?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to create a table where the first column is sized to fit the content and the rest of columns are of equal width to fill the rest of the container.

For now, I was able to make all columns of equal width (see below). But I would like the first column to be wider if needed (of minimal width to fit all content) to accommodate its content. Is it possible?

Below is an illustration of the problem:

```css
    table {  
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    table > tbody > tr > th {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <caption>Table Name</caption>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Col 1</th>
         <th>Col 2</th>
         <th>Col 3</th>
       </tr>   
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Long Row header</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Row 2</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
       </tr>   
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/orlenok41/jubkmgva/11/

Comment: Setting `table-layout: auto;` and adding `th, td { max-width: 100%; }` will get it closer to what you're looking for https://jsfiddle.net/jubkmgva/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove table fixed layout and try in this way:

```
table {  
  width: 100%;
}

table > tbody > tr > th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
}
```

If you have a number of columns different than 3 you should change the percentage on the last rule

Comment: Thanks, the number of columns is variable in my case though, it wouldn't be practical to change the CSS each time.

Comment: try to set width: auto instead of percentage

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
table {  max-width: 100%; }
table > thead > tr > th { max-width: 100px;  }
table > thead > tr > th:first-child {  width: auto; max-width: 100%;  }
```